# Change Powershell Output Property

Tags: powershell, output

I'm working on a script that compares the content of two directories with files of the same name and returns files that are different. The `property` I'm using to determine if the files are different are `LastWriteTime` and `Size`.

Here is my current script:

```
$var1 = Get-ChildItem -path C:\proj\BIN\ -Recurse 
$var2 = Get-ChildItem -path C:\proj2\BIN\ -Recurse 
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $var1 -DifferenceObject $var2 -Property Name, LastWriteTime, Size | Sort-Object Name
```

Here is my current output:

```
Name          LastWriteTime          Size SideIndicator
----          -------------          ---- -------------
folder1       6/1/2018 3:20:37 PM         =>
folder1       5/21/2018 12:08:36 PM       <=
folder2       6/1/2018 3:20:37 PM         =>
folder2       5/21/2018 12:08:36 PM       <=
CustomReports 6/1/2018 3:20:37 PM         =>
CustomReports 5/21/2018 12:08:39 PM       <=
folder3       6/1/2018 3:20:38 PM         =>
folder3       5/21/2018 12:08:38 PM       <=
blank.XML     6/1/2018 3:37:49 PM         =>
blank.XML     11/22/2017 12:36:04 PM      <=
```

As far as I know, the reason size is empty is because they are the same size (which they are). If this is true, no problem. If it happens to be just a coincidence, then I will need to correct it.

EDIT: `size` is incorrect. `length` is the correct `property`.

I want to change the output from just `Name` to the `Fullname`. If I change my it in my script it will list every file because they are in different directories.

I have added this pipe to the last line to this instead:

```
| Format-Table -property FullName, LastWriteTime, Size
```

From my understanding it the script should `compare-object` based off `name, lastWriteTime, size` and from those results `sort-object` by `name` and then return the `fullname, lastWriteTime, size` from those results.

My new output is:

```
FullName LastWriteTime          Size
-------- -------------          ----
         6/1/2018 3:20:37 PM
         5/21/2018 12:08:36 PM
         6/1/2018 3:20:37 PM
         5/21/2018 12:08:36 PM
         6/1/2018 3:20:37 PM
         5/21/2018 12:08:39 PM
         6/1/2018 3:20:38 PM
```

Comment: `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances don't have a `.Size` property, only a `.Length` property; `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instances (directories aka folders) have neither.

Comment: Thanks! Implemented it and saw the change instantly.

Comment: Glad to hear it; when in doubt, pipe a command's output to `Get-Member` to inspect its members (properties and methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-Property` with `Compare-Object`, the output objects *only* have the specified properties.

To *pass the input objects through*<sup>[1]</sup>
, add the `-PassThru` switch.

In your case that should make the `.FullName` property available on the output from `Compare-Object` / `Sort-Object`.

To put it all together:

```
Compare-Object $var1 $var2 -PassThru -Property Name, LastWriteTime, Length | 
  Sort-Object Name | 
    Format-Table FullName, LastWriteTime, Length
```

---

<sup>[1] With `-PassThru` the objects being passed through are augmented with a `.SideIndicator` `NoteProperty` member (a property with a static value added by PowerShell), so that you can still filter the output objects by what side (`-ReferenceObject` vs. `-DifferenceObject`) a given object was unique to.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try and compare on multiple properties, why not just compare on the hash of the contents. Something like this:

```
$var1 = Get-ChildItem -path C:\proj\BIN\ -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 | Sort Hash
$var2 = Get-ChildItem -path C:\proj2\BIN\ -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 | Sort Hash

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $var1 -DifferenceObject $var2 -Property Hash, {Split-Path $_.Path -leaf} -PassThru
```